# Least memory-intensive Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, collections, memory-optimization

Apart from rolling my own collection, I'm wondering which existing (.NET 3.5) Collection and IDictionary uses the least amount of memory.

I'm currently using a

- List<int>, where I only add items and later iterate over it.
- Dictionary<int,int>, where I only set and get key-value pairs.

NOTE: I'm doing mature optimization.

EDIT: I do not know the size in advance, but approximately, the dictionary will grow to about 789679 elements and the list will contain, in average, 10-20 elements.

Comment: How many elements (on average)?  Do you know the sizes in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save some memory at the cost of CPU cycles:

```
int[] data;
{
   List<int> temp = ....;
   // fill the list
   data = temp.ToArray();
}
```

When you know the number of elements beforehand you can eliminate a few steps.

A Dictionary is not so easy to replace.

Comment: I can't seem to find any information about space-efficiency of Dictionary or Dictionary-like classes (Hashtable, specialized dictionaries...), when the number of elements grow.

Comment: You can replace a Dictionary with a sorted array and then do a BinarySearch. Depending on the complexity of the key it could be simple to do.

Comment: Because of the nature of my problem, I might be able to replace the dictionary with a pre-allocated array of ints.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing is always a trade-off between space and performance. The least memory-intensive implementation of both a list and dictionary interface is always going to be a flat array. Of course, this means that your dictionary performance is going to be **terrible**, and insertion performance (for either) will be *worse*!

For a list of 10-20 elements, frankly: don't even investigate. Just use `List<T>`. For such an utterly trivial volume of data there is no sensible question to answer.

Even 789679 isn't huge. However, if your emphasis is on **memory**, then simply pre-sorting the data is probably your best bet. You could then use binary-search to find the items. Not quite as fast as a hash-table implementation, but much less memory: just 2 arrays (or a single array of tuples). Or in other words: use [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)